# How do I count how often a column value changes in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame like this:

```
    id  some_value
0   tag1    v1
1   tag1    v2
2   tag1    v1
3   tag2    v2
4   tag2    v2
5   tag2    v3
```

and I would like to know how often for each id the value in `some_value` changed. So for `tag1` that would be twice (because it changes first from `v1` to `v2` and then back), for `tag2` it would be once. I have solved the problem like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['tag1', 'tag1', 'tag1', 'tag2', 'tag2','tag2'], 'some_value': ['v1','v2','v1','v2','v2','v3']})
mask = df['id'] == df['id'].shift(-1)
df['changed'] = df['some_value'] != df['some_value'].shift(-1)
df[mask].groupby('id').sum()
```

The code works fine in that it returns

```
    changed
id  
tag1    2.0
tag2    1.0
```

Is there a more elegant solution to this?

Comment: This question is more suitable for [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to achieve this would be:

```
def numChanges(x):
    return sum(x.iloc[:-1] != x.shift(-1).iloc[:-1])

df.groupby('id').agg({
    'some_value' : numChanges
})
```

Please note that if the id column is unsorted, the results would differ, so your solution may produce incorrect results, unless you intend it to be that way.

As an example, below dataset would yield tag2 value as 5 with my solution, but 3 as per yours. Technically, the correct answer would be 5, but if your id variable is sorted, it will not make any difference.

```
pd.concat([df]*3)  #My solution outputs 5 changes for tag2 and yours will give 3 only
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, especially for pointing out the ordering issue.